# Извлечение телефонных номеров из поля произвольного формата

Tags: алгоритм, регулярные-выражения, миграция

Есть поле в базе, которое содержит номера телефонов и имеет произвольный формат. т.е. каких то валидаторов на нём не было.
Надо из этого поля *phoneInfo* достать регулярным выражением два номера телефонов, учитывая:

- все номера только 9-и значные и могут содержать в начале 2 или 9, т.е
  923456789 или 223456789
- могут содержать различные разделители без особых правил (пробелы, /, -), например:
  91 / 123-45 67
- могут содержать код страны +123 или (123), его не учитывать, т.е. (123) 912345678, действительный номер 912345678
- оба номера могут разделяются с: пробел(ы), /, -, причём этот символ являются разделителем только если с правой стороны находится действительный номер как описано выше, например: 243 / 91-23 45 678, действителен второй номер 912345678

Стоит ешё задача, к каждому "не попаданию" выдать причину, поэтому одним выражением наверное не получится.

ЯП не важен, диалект тоже в принципе нет (может perl). Поэтому готовый код я не ожидаю, если кто-то предложит, пойму любой. А так псевдокода или даже просто совета хватит.

Пример результата: `"243 / 91-23 45 678" result: "", "less as 9 digit",  "912345678", "ok"`

Пробую так (псевдокод):

```
// убираю всё лишнее
phoneNorm = replace (phoneInfo, "([(+]\d{3}\)?|\s+)", "")
phoneNorm = replace (phoneNorm, "(\d{1,8})[ /-](\d{1,8})", "\1\2")
// вытягиваю оба номера
phoneNo1 = substr (phoneNorm, "\d{9}", 1)
phoneNo2 = substr (phoneNorm, "\d{9}", 2)
```

Можно ли как-то поизяшней? И как организовать информацию по несовпадениям?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Могло бы сработать что-то вроде [`\d(?:[\h/-]*\d){8}`](https://regex101.com/r/WjRWOW/1), но в `243 / 91-23 45 678` найдет `243 / 91-23 45`. Если попробовать  [`\d(?:[\h/-]*\d){8}(?!\s*\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/WjRWOW/2), то не найдет тех номеров, что идут подряд. Так что разберитесь с последним условием, как только определитесь с границами номера, тогда и ответ будет.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew А что не так с последним условием? Оно так в БД, как я могу с ним разобраться?

Comment: *только если с правой стороны находится действительный номер* — как это понимать? Так как текст анализируется слева направо, в `243 / 91-23 45 678` сначала в поле зрения попадает `243 / 91-23 45`, и эта подстрока отвечает вышеперечисленным требованиям. Каким образом можно её "отбросить" (fail)? [`\b\d(?:[\h/-]*\d){8}\b(?![\h/-]*\d(?!(?:[\h/-]*\d){8}))`](https://regex101.com/r/WjRWOW/3)? Тут номер находится как целое слово, только если за ним нет разделителя, за которым следует цифра, которая не является первой цифрой следующего номера.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Сначала не учитывать что находится слева, т.е от `[ /-] 912/34 56 78`,  здесь слева действительный номер.  Если вы пытаетесь вытянуть всё одной регуляркой, то, как упомянается в вопросе, это не обязательно. Будет завёрнуто в функцию и сколько тамм будет промежуточных результатов, неважно, главное конечный резултат.  Спрашивайте, если что-то ещё не понятно.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите 1) извлечь все подстроки, отвечающие шаблону `[ /0-9-]+`, 2) начиная от последнего символа, справа налево, найти  подстроки по шаблону `\d(?:[\h/-]*\d){8}`. Так?

Comment: Хмм, примерно так, как точно я решил я уже не помню, код на работе. Помню:  сначала  все такие подстроки нашёл `([ /-]) 912/34 56 78` и заменил группу на неиспользуемый символ как новый разделитель `|`, далее выкинул все символы кроме [\|\d], потом достал оба номера, до `|` и после. Не очень, длинно, но заработало.

Comment: Напишите сами, мне тут далеко не всё ясно.

Comment: Прийдётся, тем не менее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант на php:

```
<?php
function numposOfPhonesDelim($str)
{
    $foundDigits = 0;
    $i = strlen($str);
    while ($i > 0) {
        if (!ctype_digit($str[$i-- - 1])) {
            continue;
        }
        if (++$foundDigits == 9) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $i;
}

function sanitizied($str)
{
    return preg_replace("/\D/", "", $str);
}

function validateResponse($phone)
{
    if (strlen($phone) != 9) {
        return "less as 9 digit";
    }
    if ($phone[0] != '2' && $phone[0] != '9') {
        return "invalid number";
    }
    return "ok";
}

function validate($str)
{
    $pos = numposOfPhonesDelim($str);
    if ($pos) {
        $phone1 = sanitizied(substr($str, 0, $pos));
        $phone2 = sanitizied(substr($str, $pos));
    } else {
        $phone1 = sanitizied($str);
        $phone2 = "";
    }
    return [
        'input' => $str,
        'result' => [
            [
                'number1' => $phone1,
                'resp' => validateResponse($phone1)
            ],
            [
                'number2' => $phone2,
                'resp' => validateResponse($phone2)
            ]
        ]
    ];
}

// =================================
var_dump(validate("243 / 91-23 45 678"));
var_dump(validate("243 / 1-23 45 678"));
var_dump(validate("243"));
var_dump(validate("+21 / 23 45 678 / 91-23 45 678"));
var_dump(validate("+71 / 23 45 678 / 91-23 45 678"));
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27e8c2bcd89540e0e58879065e1b16c8c2dde650)

Comment: Спасибо, так будет работать.